# rxjs: Get the last response of the request

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have this request

```
  filter(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.getValues(term))
    );
  }
```

This one works but, i have many same response.
How I can just have the last response ?

The request is use for a search engine forms, when the user use the inputs, a call is fire,

Exemple; input "f" -> call ws with query "f"
input "fo" -> cal ws with query "fo"

so in this exemple, i will have two responses.... and I want just the last.
I don't know if is clear....

this code call the service,

component.ts

```
 this.filterService.filter(this.filterTerm$).subscribe((res) => {
        this.res= res;
        console.log(res);
      });
```

Thank

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking to prevent additional http requests? or just asking to prevent it emitting values with the same results?

Comment: @arvil: just prevent it emitting values with the same results

Comment: i feel like the problem lies on how you're subscribing to the observable, can you show a little more code on how you're calling and subscribing to the observable?

Comment: @arvil, I add the call from my component

Comment: I think I understand, let me whip up an answer for you

Comment: I think , if i call 4 times the WS, i have 4 responses. But I want just 1 response. Thank

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you're already passing an observable to the function call that starts another stream of observables - here is something that should get you what you need:

```
this.filterTerm$
   .pipe(
     debounceTime(1000),
     distinctUntilChanged(),
     switchMap((term) => this.getValues(term))
   )
   .subscribe((res) => {
    this.res = res;
    console.log(res);
  });
```